# Using PDO FETCH_CLASS with polymorphic class

Tags: mysql, class, pdo, polymorphism

I have a php classes like:

```
class bar{
    public $value;
}

class foo extends bar{
    public $value;
    public $name;
}
```

In database:

```
-bar table:
value
-----
'bar value 1'
'bar value 2'

-foo table:
value        |  name
-------------+--------------
'foo value 1'| 'foo name 1'
'foo value 2'| 'foo name 2'
```

How can I store and fetch them by using PDO FETCH_CLASS?

Comment: If `Foo` extends `Bar`, you don't need to define the `$value` field again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

potential coolness

```
select 'foo', name, value from footable;
```

`PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE` uses the first column in the results to determine the classname to instantiate for that row.

```
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE);
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't appear to need special treatment. As long as you know whether you're requesting a `foo` or a `bar`, you just pass that as a string to the fetch call.  Since you have different tables for `foo` and `bar`, I assume you have determined when querying which one you will need.

```
// Build a foo
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'foo');
$stmt->fetch()

// Or build a bar
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'bar');
$stmt->fetch()
```